# Counting none duplicate elements in a Hash Table Lisp

Tags: loops, hashmap, lisp

```
(dolist (i list (hash-table-count hash))
  (setf (gethash i hash) t))))
```

The above code is an extract from one of my Lecture tutorials that I missed due to illness, I understand some of the code but I can't figure out how its counting the none identical elements.

What I know: We're looping over the list and for each i in list we set the key to i in the hash table and the value to true.

Comment: so, what is the question?

Comment: A hash cannot contain a given key two or more times. Hash tables are exploited for squashing duplicate keys. It's what they do; they are a *dynamic set* data structure. A set either contains an element or it does not; it doesn't contain an element two or three times. If you add a key to the hash twice, it only exists in the has once, and is associated with the most recent value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example: if `list` is `(3 3 5 6 6 6 9)`, the loop will examine each list element in turn, and set these hash keys to `t`: `3`, `5`, `6`, and `9`.  Since `3` and `6` are duplicated in the list, no new hash key will be created for those elements.  Finally `hash-table-count` returns the number of keys in the hash table, i.e. `4`.